# Get daily mean of AOD from MCD19A2 in GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, modis, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I tried to get daily mean of AOD from MCD19A2 in GEE, but my mean function always returns zero.

```
// function to add date to image collection from system:time_start
var writeDate = function(image){
  var date = ee.Date(image.get("system:time_start"))
  var day = date.get('day')
  var month = date.get('month')
  var year = date.get('year')
  var image_dated = image.set('day',day)
                          .set('month', month)
                          .set('year', year)
  return image_dated
}
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES')
                  .select('Optical_Depth_055')
                  .filterDate('2016-05-15','2020-08-31' )
                  .filterBounds(Hanoi)
                  .map(writeDate)
                  ;

var band_viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 800,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

var first =modis.first()
print ("modis_first",first)
Map.addLayer(first, band_viz, "first")

var date = first.get("system:time_start")
// print("date",date)

var date_easyToRead = (ee.Date(date))
print("date_easyToRead",date_easyToRead)

var day = date_easyToRead.get('day')
print('day',day)

var month = date_easyToRead.get('month')
print('month',month)

var year = date_easyToRead.get('year')
print('year',year)

// var first_dated = first.set('month', month)
//         .set('year', year)
var first_dated = writeDate(first)

        
print('first_dated',first_dated)


var mean = modis.mean()

print("mean", mean)
var meanWithProperties = mean.copyProperties(modis.first(),["system:time_start"])
print("meanWithProperties", meanWithProperties)

// Map.addLayer(ee.Image(byMonth.first()));
var days = ee.List.sequence(15,18);
var months = ee.List.sequence(5,5);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2016, 2016);

// // var a = months.first()
// print("a",months)

var byMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function (m) {
      return days.map(function (d) {
      return modis
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y,  'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m,  'month'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(d, d, 'day_of_month'))
        .mean()
        .set('day', d)
        .set('month', m)
        .set('year', y)
        .clip(Hanoi)
        // .set("year", (y+m).getInfo())
        ;
  });
});
}).flatten());
print ("byMonthYear", byMonthYear)
Map.addLayer(byMonthYear.first(),band_viz, 'dailyComp')


var reprojected2 = byMonthYear.toBands();
var areaofinterest = reprojected2.clip(Hanoi);
print("areaofinterest",areaofinterest)


Export.image.toDrive({
  image: areaofinterest,
  description: 'MCD19dailyTest5',
  region: Hanoi,
  scale: 1000
});
```